# SEO and changes to page addresses

Tags: url, routes, seo, yii2

I have site that has been around for a few years and is pretty well positioned in google search. Now I would like to rebuild the site by introducing a framework. One of the things that framework changes is that everything is routed through index.php and urls are being rewritten.

Currently subpages look like this (example):

`mysite.com/home.php` `mysite.com/work.php`

after the framework introduction they will look like this:

`mysite.com/home` `mysite.com/work`

Now can anyone tell me will this hurt/reset page ranks, and if so, how can I make a framework (Yii2) to append .php to controller names and would that be wise...

Comment: Off topic - How search engines will rank/display your site is not programming

Comment: I guess you just need to add 301 redirects in your htaccess of your project, so the old urls will "migrate" to the new url with no loss. Sorry I could not find a good source of material other than http://www.webconfs.com/how-to-redirect-a-webpage.php (htaccess redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with Yii2,

You can create all your pages under the site controller, and add the following to your project:

**config/main.php**

```
'urlManager' => [
    'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
    // Disable index.php
    'showScriptName' => false,
    // Disable r= routes
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    // Add suffix
    'suffix' => '.php',
    // General rules, and remove controller name for site
    'rules' => [
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<alias:home|work|etc>' => 'site/<alias>',
    ],
],
```

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Or, if more convenient, create a controller for each of those pages. But you'll figure that out.

Docs:
[urlManager](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html)
[urlManager - Suffix](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#$suffix-detail)

**$suffix public property**

> The URL suffix used when in 'path' format. For example, ".html" can be used so that the URL looks like pointing to a static HTML page. This property is used only if $enablePrettyUrl is true.
>   public string $suffix = null

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the suffix option,  alias:... rules did the trick. No idea why would someone downvote a perfectly great answer! Perhaps all the righteous powers that be didnt like an answer to an 'off topic' question.